# SQL Error -- ORA-00936: missing expression

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am trying to insert a ref in a nested table but I keep getting the error SQL Error: ORA-00936: missing expression

The relevant types and tables are as follows:

```
create type TP1_PROPRIETE as object (
  NO_PROPRIETE number(10),
  ADRESSE_PRO varchar2(20),
  VILLE_PRO varchar2(20),
  NB_PIECES_PRO number(2));
/

create type TP1_CAPROPRO as object (
  REF_PROPRIETE_CAPROPRO ref TP1_PROPRIETE);
/

create type TP1_CAPROPRO_NT as table of TP1_CAPROPRO;
/

create type TP1_PARTENAIRE as object (
  NOM_COMPLET_PAR varchar2(40));
/

create type TP1_PARTENAIRE_NT as table of TP1_PARTENAIRE;
/

create type TP1_PROPRIETAIRE as object (
  NO_PROPRIETAIRE number(10),
  NOM_COMPLET_PROR varchar2(40),
  REF_PARTENAIRES_PROR TP1_PARTENAIRE_NT,
  REF_PROPRIETES_PROR TP1_CAPROPRO_NT);
/

create table TP1_PROPRIETAIRE_T of TP1_PROPRIETAIRE
  nested table REF_PARTENAIRES_PROR store as TP1_PARTENAIRE_NT_PROR
  nested table REF_PROPRIETES_PROR store as TP1_CAPROPRO_NT_PROR;
/

create table TP1_PROPRIETE_T of TP1_PROPRIETE (
  constraint CT_NB_PIECES_NON_NEG check (NB_PIECES_PRO > 0));
/
```

And here are the inserts:

```
insert into TP1_PROPRIETE_T
  values(1465798654,
         '1170 Victory',
         'New York',
         5);
/

insert into TP1_PROPRIETAIRE_T
  values(9654255475,
         'Mike Ross',
         TP1_PARTENAIRE_NT(TP1_PARTENAIRE('Andre Ross')),
         TP1_CAPROPRO_NT(TP1_CAPROPRO(select ref(p)
                                        from TP1_PROPRIETE_T p
                                        where p.NO_PROPRIETE = 1465798654)));
/
```

I get the following error when executing the last insert:

> ```
> Error starting at line 117 in command: insert into TP1_PROPRIETAIRE_T 
>  values(9654255475,
>           'Mike Ross',
>           TP1_PARTENAIRE_NT(TP1_PARTENAIRE('Andre Ross')),
>           TP1_CAPROPRO_NT(TP1_CAPROPRO(select ref(p)
>                                          from TP1_PROPRIETE_T p
>                                          where p.NO_PROPRIETE = 1465798654)))
>  Error at Command Line:121 Column:39
>  Error report: SQL
>  Error: ORA-00936: missing expression
>  00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"
>  *Cause:    
>  *Action:
> ```

From what I have read from SO and other forums, the error is most likely somewhere in the last select ref(p)... but the syntax seems fine to me, so I really don't know why I get this error. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `insert . . . select` (personal preference), but your problem is the lack of extra parentheses for the subquery:

```
insert into TP1_PROPRIETAIRE_T
    select 9654255475, 'Mike Ross',
           TP1_PARTENAIRE_NT(TP1_PARTENAIRE('Andre Ross')),
           TP1_CAPROPRO_NT(TP1_CAPROPRO( (select ref(p)
                                          from TP1_PROPRIETE_T p
                                          where p.NO_PROPRIETE = 1465798654
                                         )
                                       ))
    from dual;
```